# How could we specify the times of running a tactic

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

I want to run a tactic several times.
For instance, I want to execute `apply lemma1` two times but do not like to write like `apply lemma1. apply lemma1`. Is there a command such that I can apply `apply lemma1.` for just two times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`do 2 apply lemma1.`

There is a whole page on tactic combinators and how to create new tactics: https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/ltac.html#do-loop